# Call table row name attribute instead of .eq(n)

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want this code to be reusable ,instead of this :

`$(this).closest("tr").find("td input").eq(1).val()`

i was hoping for calling it by name using :

(`($(this).closest("tr").find("td input").attr("name")`)  so i dont have to set every `.eq(n)`
but its not working :

here's my jquery code :

```
   $('.tdiv').on("click", "#tddelete", function () {
        if ($(this).closest("tr").find("td input").eq(1).val() == "ADD") alert("add");
        else alert("change");
    });
```

see this working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gu1t4y4m/1/) for my first code.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do: filter elements by attribute name?

Comment: Don't use same `id` on more than one element. IDs must be unique.

Comment: @hindmost no filtering, just want to get the value of the  input whose attribute nami is flag

Comment: @bumbumpaw This task include **filtering** operation (input whose attribute name is flag)

Comment: ahh.ok sir  @hindmost include filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should not use id for multiple elements, so change `id="tddelete"` to `class="tddelete"` for all button elements.

```
<input type="button" class="tddelete" />
```

You can find for input element present in next `td` of button's parent `td`. Don't forget to put `name` attribute for input elements.

```
$('.tdiv').on("click", ".tddelete", function () {
    var val = $(this).closest("td").siblings().find("input[name=flag]").val();
    alert(val);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gu1t4y4m/18/)**

Comment: unmark as answer for now,but when i try to add another input,only the first input value it will show,which is empty,also when rearranging td's

Comment: after adding more inputs, which input value you want? Is there any specific condition or class of input?

Comment: display only the value of that input with the attribute name flag sir

Comment: you mean like this `<input type="text" value="CHANGE" flag />` ?

Comment: sorry for unclear question sir, see this http://jsfiddle.net/gu1t4y4m/16/ notice that only the first row is working because the input whose attribute name is flag is on the first input,the rest is not on the first row.

Comment: see my updated answer and link. It is able to alert() all input with name="flag", no matter what is the position of input.

Comment: yes! `siblings()` is the best! anyways,just want to know if this jquery is workingg on IE8? @Bhushan Kawadkar

Comment: Yes it should work. See [this](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) for more information on siblings

Answer (score 2):

`id` attributes should be unique. Also you're looking for the attribute selector in jQuery. EG.

`$(this).closest("tr").find("td input[type='text']").val();`

**JS**

```
$('.tdiv').on("click", ".tddelete", function () {
    var inputVal = $(this).closest("tr").find("td input[type='text']").val();
    alert(inputVal);
});
```

**[UPDATE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gu1t4y4m/4/)**

---

**UPDATE BASED ON COMMENTS**

It appears that you could have more than one input of type `text` in your table cell. As such i would suggest adding a class to the input element you are looking to get the value from.

**HTML**

```
<table class="tdiv">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" class="tddelete" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="getVal" value="ADD" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" class="tddelete" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="getVal" value="CHANGE" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$('.tdiv').on("click", ".tddelete", function () {
    var inputVal = $(this).closest("tr").find(".getVal").val();
    alert(inputVal);
});
```

**[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gu1t4y4m/8/)**

Comment: wheres the use of attribute name flag? this is not useful to me if i do have many input of tds?

Comment: your example shows you wanting to get to just a single input of type "text". I will update answer to use classes instead of input attributes

Comment: @bumbumpaw updated, however, the answer you have selected, doesnt appear to solve the comment you just made on my solution

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using attr, use an attribute selector in your find method `.find("td input[name=somename]")`

```
$('.tdiv').on("click", "#tddelete", function () {
    if ($(this).closest("tr").find("td input[name=somename]").eq(1).val() == "ADD") alert("add");
    else alert("change");
});
```